Can we print a text only once that is inside a loop without making it print again and again until the loop ends?
I am trying to make a countdown. Now when I use a while loop to achieve that, I also need to print count down, but what happens is that the countdown takes place in separate lines printing the text over and over again. I want the loop to print the text only once but keep changing the value of countdown until countdown is over.
My code is:
      clearing = True
      countdown = 3
      while clearing:
        while countdown > 0:
          print(f"Clearing console in {countdown} second(s)")
          time.sleep(1)
          countdown -= 1
        os.system('clear')
        clearing = False

and this is the result I am currently achieving in the console rn:
Clearing console in 3 second(s)
Clearing console in 2 second(s)
Clearing console in 1 second(s)

see the print repeats evertime until countdown == 0
what I want is for the loop to print the text only once but keep changing the value of countdown inside the text
something like this:
Clearing console in '3 then 2 then 1' second(s)


Try adding the print() parameters end="\r" and flush=True

Why do you have a second "clearing" loop? When do you expect that to really occur? If you want to clear the text you need to do it in the loop that is running.

print(f"Clearing console in {countdown} second(s)", end="\r", flush=True)

I am posting the answer from the comments:
 clearing = True
      countdown = 3
      while clearing:
        while countdown > 0:
          print(f"Clearing console in {countdown}  second(s)", end='\r', flush=True)
          time.sleep(1)
          countdown -= 1
        os.system('clear')
        clearing = False

I also found another way to achieve this effect:
clearing = True
countdown = 3
while clearing:
    while countdown > 0:
        os.system('cls')
        print(f"Exiting in {countdown}  second(s)")
        time.sleep(1)
        countdown -= 1
        os.system('cls')
    os.system('cls')
    clearing = False


Well, actually there is something you can do about it.
print(f"Clearing console in {count}  second(s)", end='\r', flush=True)

I suggest you to read what carriage return is and something about flush too.

https://www.ascii-code.com/glossary/carriage-return
How can I flush the output of the print function?

